# NSOperation(s) leaks only on iOS 3 device

Tags: iphone, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsautoreleasepool

I have some NSOperations subclasses that handle CoreData imports. I believe i've ticked most of the non-main thread issues

- I create my own autorelease pool in the
  `main` method
- I create a `NSManagedObjectContext` for each
  operation

These operations are loaded into a NSOperationQueue, with the maximum number of concurrent operations set 1.

The code works perfectly on a iOS 4.0.1, however on a iOS 3.1.3 device a get a lot of log messages like the following

```
*** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5f926c0 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

NSOperation Subclass main method

```
-(void) main{

    NSAutoreleasePool   *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    @try {
    //Start Operation
    //====================================
    NSManagedObjectID       *objID      = nil;
    NSError             *err        = nil;
    id                              user            = nil;

    if( !(userID = [self __lookup:[self userID] inContext: [self threadContext]]) ){

        //Set the name of the element
        user = [[self threadContext] objectWithID:objID];
        //Update the name
        [user setValue:@"John Doe"  forKey:@"name"];
        [user setValue:@"Hello world" forKey:@"status"];
    }


    if( ![[self threadContext] save:&err] ){
        DebugLog(@"Couldn't savechanges %@", err);
    }

    //====================================
    //End Operation
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        DebugLog(@"Exception %@",e);
    }
    //====================================


   [pool drain];
}
```

The `__lookup:inContext:` method

```
-(NSManagedObjectID*) __lookup:(id)aID inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*) aContext{

    NSPredicate             *predicate      = nil;
    NSEntityDescription     *entity;
    NSFetchRequest          *fetchRequest   = nil;
    NSError                 *err            = nil;

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@",aID];

    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:aContext];

    fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    //Only fetch id's for speed
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];

    return [[aContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err] lastObject];

}
```

Most of the other methods instance methods, ie `threadContext` look similar to the `__lookup:inContext:` method. I'm aware that i don't create Autorelease pools for the instance methods, but according to my understanding of how autorelease works, as long as these methods are only called inside the main method, after the `NSAutoreleasePool` has been created, the outer most pool should be used. I create objects such as the NSManagedObjectContext lazily, and in most cases don't use the `start` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, This operation was launching a NSURLConnection using the advice in an [article](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/) by Dave Dribin. However, where possible i try to never cut and paste other peoples code, so i can always filter what i am putting into my own code.

Turns out i forgot to add this check

```
if( ![NSThread isMainThread] ){
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) 
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
    return;
}
```

Which ensures that the `start` method runs on the main thread, where a `NSAutoreleasePool` already exists. Simple mistake, easy solution.